# how do you construct an array of arrays in JSON

Tags: php, json, ios5, ios6

if have several arrays call them colors,plants,cars,family
each or these arrays is the same length 5 items

I want to create another array that is called grouping
it is set up like

project will contain group which contains

```
group[0]=>( color=>color[0],plant=>plant[0],car=>car[0],family=>family[0] )
group[1]=>( color=>color[1],plant=>plant[1],car=>car[1],family=>family[1] )
group[2]=>( color=>color[2],plant=>plant[2],car=>car[2],family=>family[2] )
group[3]=>( color=>color[3],plant=>plant[3],car=>car[3],family=>family[3] )
group[4]=>( color=>color[4],plant=>plant[4],car=>car[4],family=>family[4] )
```

How do I set this up into a for loop
In actuality I have 50 items and each has 13 elements

and then I will use the PHP json_encode to put it into JSON so I can transfer it

I need to get it to a iOS dictionary so I can call up one element of group and get easy access to any of the elements

if I call group3 I can get all of the matching elements

How would this be setup in PHP

Sorry to make it clear what is shown above is what I want to end up with.

Comment: The sample code you've provided, is that the desired construct? Or the one you're starting with? It's not very clear.

Answer (score 0):

Please correct me if i'm wrong. but the easiest way ever i did such things is as follows:

```
var group= [];

for(var i=0;i<50;i++)
{

    var aGroup={};
    for(var j=0;j<13;j++)
    {
    aGroup.color[j]=color[j]; // colors array
    aGroup.plant[j]=plant[j]; //plant array
    aGroup.family[j]=family[j];//family array
    }
    group[i]=aGroup; //finally add aGroup to group

    }
    //to access color you can do following
    group[0].aGroup.color[0]; //not tested
```

let me know if you find any issue.